# Parse JSON in iOS APP

Tags: jquery, ios, json

i'm working on an iOS App and i have to decode a json response.

The response data looks like this:

```
[{"owner":"123456789","id":"1","liked":"0","unliked":"0","nickname":"jack","filename":"name_image.jpg","user":null,"image":null,"type":null}]
```

This is the code in my app:

```
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];            
NSString *owner = [json valueForKey:@"owner"];      
NSLog(@"\n\nowner: %@", owner);
```

In the log i see this:

```
owner: (
    3402379524
)
```

How can i remove round brackets and get the right value?
I tried to use this too:

```
NSDictionary *owner_image = [json objectForKey:@"owner"];
```

but the application crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have array of dictionary, so you need to first get array object and after you can get value from dictionary.

```
NSArray* json   = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *owner = json[0][@"owner"];  
NSLog(@"\n\nowner: %@", owner);
```

To better understand structure see following image.

[image]

Comment: I suggest using `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey:` unless you specifically need KVC. Also, why mix old and new syntax? Do `json[0][@"owner"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary *owner_image = [((NSDictionary *)[json objectForIndex:0]) objectForKey:@"owner"];
```

Comment: FYI - there is no need for the cast and the return value of the rhs is not an `NSDictionary`, it is an `NSString` (or `NSNumber` maybe).

Comment: i receive this error: No visible interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'objectForIndex'

Comment: Sure, NSDictionary not needed. Above is the correct answer (the same sense as mine)